# Sequelize hooks not triggering

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, hook

I have a sequelize schema as follows :

```
import sequelize from "../config/sequelize-config";
import { INTEGER, FLOAT, DATE } from "sequelize";

    var UserRatingSchema = sequelize.define(
        'user_rating', {
        id: {
            type: INTEGER, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true
        },
        user_id: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: false },
        box_id: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: false },
        product_id: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: false },
        rating: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: false },
        created_on: { type: DATE, allowNull: true },
        updated_on: { type: DATE, allowNull: false }
    },
        {
            indexes: [{
                unique: false,
                fields: ['id', 'user_id']
            }],
            classMethods: {},
            timestamps: false
        },
        {
            hooks: {
                afterUpdate: function (user, options, fn) {
                    console.log("works after the update on user rating table")
                },
                afterCreate: function (user, options, fn) {
                    console.log("works after the create on user rating table")
                }
            }

        });

    export default UserRatingSchema;
```

Updating the data as follows:

```
import UserRatingSchema from "../db-schemas/user-rating";
rateUserExperience(params) {
    let data = new Observable(observer => {
        UserRatingSchema.update({
          user_id: params.userId,
          box_id: params.bookingId,
          product_id: params.productId,
          rating: params.rating,
          created_on: Date.now(),
          updated_on: Date.now()
        },
          { where: { user_id: params.userId } }
        )
        console.log("Rating done successfully")
           })
           .catch(error => {
             observer.error(error);
           }); 
          }
    });
    return data;
  }
```

But **i am not geting the console message after insertion/ Updation**. Any idea to solve this problem?

Specs are the following

node version : **v8.16.2**

sequelize version : **sequelize@4.42.0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with :

```
import sequelize from "../config/sequelize-config";
import { INTEGER, FLOAT, DATE } from "sequelize";

    var UserRatingSchema = sequelize.define(
        'user_rating', {
        id: {
            type: INTEGER, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true
        },
        user_id: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: false },
        box_id: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: false },
        product_id: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: false },
        rating: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: false },
        created_on: { type: DATE, allowNull: true },
        updated_on: { type: DATE, allowNull: false }
    },
        {
            indexes: [{
                unique: false,
                fields: ['id', 'user_id']
            }],
            classMethods: {},
            timestamps: false,
            hooks: {
                afterUpdate: function (user, options, fn) {
                    console.log("works after the update on user rating table")
                },
                afterCreate: function (user, options, fn) {
                    console.log("works after the create on user rating table")
                }
            }

        });

    export default UserRatingSchema;
```